# Input placeholder overrides date

Tags: css, html, input

In Chrome, when date is not fully given by user, placeholder overrides date:

[image]

delete by hand month:

[image]

Is there any solution to code that placeholder has to go on date place iff when there is no year, no month and no day in input.

Source code:

```
<input
    id="tf-datefrom-text"
    class="form-control"
    type="date"
    placeholder="Select date"
    ng-blur="checkValidation()"
    min="{{vm.minDate}}"
    max="{{vm.maxDate}}"
    ng-model="vm.dateFrom"
    aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
    required
    ng-required="true"/>
```

And there is no CSS for the input field.

Comment: In which browser do you experience this? Also, could you please provide html and css code? Do you use some css framework (like Material design) as well?

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi Answered in question.

Comment: If you use material design light (sorry if not), upgrading to the latest version might solve your issue as you can see here: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/243

Comment: Looks like you're using a front end framework like Angular or VueJs, could you expand in your question what you're using and some example code.

Comment: @Malcor I use AngularJS.

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi You are right, upgrade material-design helps, but I am not able to transfer You reputation points ;-)

Comment: I have posted an answer, thank you for ponting it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Material Design, upgrading to the latest version might solve your issue, because this has been a bug in earlier versions. See more in this [thread](http://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/243).